# Site parsing,extract data to an array./ Парсинг сайта с извлечением нужных данных в массив

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, steam

требуется парсер для внедрение в расширение под google chrome, парсинг торговой площадки steam, а именно лотов определенного предмета, требуемые мне данные обладают следующими селекторами
 [image: селекторы]
полное древо https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29
было попробовано многое, но возможно, по моей невнимательности были ошибки, в следствии, которых ничего не работало, теперь обращаюсь сюда, буду очень рад помощи

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, класс - `csgofloat` рисует расширение, которое у тебя установлено (и тебе нужно либо подключать сурсы к ноде\экстету что ты пишешь, либо ожидать его подключения, если ты пишешь экстет)

Во-вторых, вот для цен перебор:

```js
const arr = $('.market_listing_price.market_listing_price_with_fee');
for(let e of arr){
    console.log($(e).text().trim());
}
```

Нажать можно через [этот экстет](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-exec/caeimpdeapdimekjkkkggpibnlijlnka)

Comment: спасибо, теперь понял в чем проблема, счас буду пробывать

Comment: @user381597 я не понял, это решило проблему или чем еще могу помочь?